# Prove that the following is a field.

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

> Let $\mathcal{F}_1,\mathcal{F}_2,...$ be classes of sets in a common space $\Omega$.
>
> **(a)** Suppose that $\mathcal{F}_n$ are [fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_sets) and that $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$. Show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$ is a field.
>
> **(b)** Suppose that $\mathcal{F}_n$ are [$\sigma$-fields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigma-algebra) satisfying $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_{n+1}$. Show by example that $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$ need not be a $\sigma$-field.

**Original source:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIJdB.jpg 2.4a

Honestly, I'm really confused with this notation and what a field is etc. I get the 3 conditions for it to be a field I'm just really bad at proving them.

So far I have that for $F$ to be a field you need

i) $\Omega$ has to be an element of $\mathcal{F}$;

ii) $A\in \mathcal{F}$ implies $A'\in \mathcal{F}$;

iii) $A,B\in \mathcal{F}$ implies $A\cup B\in \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Show what you've tried. Share your ideas

Comment: The thing is, I don't even know where to begin. I know I gotta throw those three conditions. I just have no clue how to start.

Comment: If you don't even have clues, then try easier problems.

Comment: I didn't like my answer,so I deleted it until I can work on it some more. Anyone else wants to take a crack at it first,feel free. Been awhile since measure theory for me.......

Comment: I'm telling you boss, this is one of the easier ones. It's so complex that the easier ones just seem impossible. All I know is I have to prove those i) ii) and iii), the textbook is gibberish to me and there are literally 0 examples.

Answer (score 3):

**(a)** Since for all $n$ $\Omega\in \mathcal{F}_n$ then $\Omega\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$.

If $A\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$ then for all $n$, $A\in\mathcal{F}_n$. Since each $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a field then $A'\in\mathcal{F}_n$ for each $n$. Then $A'\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$.

If $A,B\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$ then for all $n$, $A,B\in\mathcal{F}_n$. Since each $\mathcal{F}_n$ is a field we must have $A\cup B\in\mathcal{F}_n$ (for each $n$). Therefore $A\cup B\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$.

> Notice how each time what we are using is that $x\in\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$ is the same as "For all $n$ $x\in A_n$".

**(b)** Here, if we are to find an example, we must exploit the main difference between field and $\sigma$-field. The difference is that in a $\sigma$-field we are able to take countable unions, instead of unions of pairs (or finite unions).

Let $\Omega=\{1,2,3,...\}$, i.e. $\Omega=\mathbb{N}$, and put $\mathcal{F}_n$ to be the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the singleton sets $\{1\},\{2\},...,\{n\}$. We can see what sets ought to be in $\mathcal{F}_n$: Unions of those singletons, their complemtents, etc. More precisely, the elements of $\mathcal{F}_n$ are sets that are either subsets of $\{1,2,...,n\}$ or their complements are subsets of this set.

It is clear that $\mathcal{F}_n\subset\mathcal{F}_n$.

We now take their union $\mathcal{F}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathcal{F}_n$. Notice that $A_n:=\{2n\}\in\mathcal{F}$. In fact $A_n\in \mathcal{F}_{2n}$. But what about $A:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$? If $A\in\mathcal{F}$ then there must be one $\mathcal{F}_m$ such that $A\in\mathcal{F}_m$. But neither $A$ not its complement are finite.